# auto как тип, который возвращает функция C++

Tags: c++, функции, классы, типы

как заставить это работать?

LazyRepeater.h

```
#include <string>
auto makeLooper(const std::string& str);
class LazyRepeater {
    std::string str;
    int pos{ 0 };
public:
    LazyRepeater(std::string str);
    char operator() ();
};
```

LazyRepeater.cpp

```
#include "LazyRepeater.h"
#include <string>
auto makeLooper(const std::string& str){
    return LazyRepeater(str);
}
LazyRepeater::LazyRepeater(std::string str){
    this->str = str;
}
char LazyRepeater::operator() () {
    char ch = this->str[this->pos];
    this->pos++;
    this->pos %= this->str.length();
    return ch;
}
```

ошибка: "makeLooper": функцию, возвращающую "auto" нельзя использовать, предварительно не определив

Comment: Не воспроизводится: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/zdo4Envfa

Comment: спасибо, поправил вопрос

Comment: Перенесите тело функции `makeLooper` в заголовочный файл после определения класса. Да и реализацию методов класса тоже можно перенести в заголовочный файл, прямо в тело класса, а LazyRepeater.cpp вообще не нужен. Изначально же почти правильно было...

Comment: а почему я не могу сделать это в разных файлах? Я считал то, что .h нужно для объявления, а .cpp для реализации

Comment: Потому что это примерно как написать в заголовочном файле шаблон, а в отдельном .cpp — реализацию :)

Comment: .cpp нужен, когда нужно создать единицу трансляции.

Answer (score 1):

Все логично. Определение функции, возвращающей `auto`, должно быть видно в той единице трансляции (.cpp-файл вместе со всеми заинклуженными хедерами), в которой ее вызывают. Потому что все типы должны быть известны во время компиляции, а вместо `auto` нельзя подставить правильный тип, не видя определения.

Поэтому `auto` в возвращаемом типе имеет смысл использовать только для функций, которые уже определены в хедере по какой-то причине (потому что они шаблоны, или `inline`) (или не в хедере а просто в том же .cpp-файле). Переносить функцию в хедер только для того, чтобы `auto` заработал - странно.

Поэтому в вашем случае проще явно указать возвращаемый тип. (Или подвинуть функцию в хедер, сделав `inline`.)